# How can I configure AppHarbor to display a unity3d file?

Tags: unity-game-engine, appharbor

I have an html file that calls a unity3d file but I get this error when I try to load it on the browser "Failed to download data file". There's an error details link, but it just says "Download failed, try again". Does anyone know what should I do?

Comment: maybe show the html file that loads it, not much anyone can help if they can't see where the error might be happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed creating a Visual Studio Project and added the mime type on the web.config

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried download the build output from the AppHarbor dashboard to confirm that the file is in there? There's more debugging suggestions in the [AppHarbor FAQ](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions).